# Какой функцией заменить getch() для Linux

Tags: c, функции, библиотеки

Есть игра про собачку. Но там используются устаревшие функции и библиотеки еще с MS-DOS как заменить их на актуальные что бы например в Linux работало. Функция getch(), библиотека conio.h и system("cls") ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){

    char mas[10][21];
    int i;
    int x = 10, y = 5;
    char key;
    int ox, oy;
    int ax = 5, ay = 3;
    srand(time(NULL));


    do{

        sprintf(mas[0], "####################");
        for (i = 1; i < 9; i++)
            sprintf(mas[i], "#                  #");
        sprintf(mas[9], "####################");

        mas[y][x] = '@';
        mas[ay][ax] = '*';

        system("cls");

        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            printf("%s\n", mas[i]);

        key = getch();

        ox = x;
        oy = y;

        if (key == 'w') y--;
        if (key == 's') y++;
        if (key == 'a') x--;
        if (key == 'd') x++;
        if(mas[y][x] == '#'){
            x = ox;
            y = oy;
        }

        if((x == ax) && (y == ay)){
            ax = rand() * 1.0 / RAND_MAX * 18 + 1;
            ay = rand() * 1.0 / RAND_MAX * 8 + 1;
        }
    }
    while(key != 'e');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Читайте [man tcsetattr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetattr). Ну, если совсем по-простому, то `system("stty clear; raw -echo");` очистит экран и переведет stdin/stdout в режим без эха, ввода символов без ожидания Enter, без сигналов, всяких преобразований вводимых-выводимых символов  и EOF. `while ((c = getchar()) != 4) putchar(c);` будет читать символы по мере их ввода и выводить. При нажатии `^D` (код 4) выход из цикла. В конце надо восстановить нормальные преобразования -- `system("stty sane");` (также прочтите [man stty](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html))

Comment: Используйте библиотеку `ncurses` - там есть функция `getch()`, для ввода без отображения символов можно перед ней вызвать `noecho()`.